# What is the proper syntax for multiple left join and where condition on the left table?

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

The following select statement returns zero results, why?

```
SELECT `post_job`.`id`,
    `post_job_description`.`title`,
    `employers_description`.`name`
FROM (`post_job`)
LEFT JOIN `post_job_description`
    ON `post_job`.`id` = `post_job_description`.`post_job_id`
LEFT JOIN `employers_description`
    ON `post_job`.`employers_id` = `employers_description`.`id`
WHERE `post_job`.`published` = 1
    AND `post_job_description`.`language` IN ('en')
    AND `employers_description`.`language` IN ('en')
    AND `post_job`.`deleted` = 0
GROUP BY `post_job_description`.`post_job_id`
LIMIT 25
```

When I remove this:

```
AND `employers_description`.`language` IN ('en')
```

it return data but the value of `employers_description`.`name` is not in **English**

post_job table:

[image]

post_job_description table:

[image]

employers_description table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `ON` clause:

```
`post_job`.`employers_id` = `employers_description`.`id`
```

is used to join  `employers_description` table to `post_job` table.

Just a *single* row is being selected from `post_job` table (according to your posted sample data):

```
id employers_id published deleted
---------------------------------
1  2            1         0
```

As per the above mentioned `ON` clause, the following one and only row from `employers_description` is being fetched by the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
name    id language
-----------------
MaIT ar 2  ar
```

Hence, this predicate:

```
`employers_description`.`language` IN ('en')
```

filters this row out, and you get no results. If you take this predicate out of the `WHERE` clause, then you get this row returned, but, as you can see from above, `language = ar`.

You have to change the `id` value of record with `name = MaIT ar` from `2` to `1`, so that both *language versions* from `employers_description` are fetched by the `LEFT JOIN` operation (as is the case in `post_job_description` table).

As a side note, perhaps you should consider normalizing `post_job_description` and `employers_description` tables by keeping `language` per post and `language` per employee info in separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

Any conditions on the table that you're joining with `LEFT JOIN` must be put into the `ON` clause. If you put it in the `WHERE` clause, the null values that are returned for rows with no match will not match this condition, and they'll filter the whole row out.

Also, your `GROUP BY` column should be from the main table, not one of the `LEFT JOIN` tables. Otherwise, all the rows with null matches will be grouped together.

So change it to

```
SELECT `post_job`.`id`,
    `post_job_description`.`title`,
    `employers_description`.`name`
FROM (`post_job`)
LEFT JOIN `post_job_description`
    ON `post_job`.`id` = `post_job_description`.`post_job_id`
        AND `post_job_description`.`language` IN ('en')
LEFT JOIN `employers_description`
    ON `post_job`.`employers_id` = `employers_description`.`id`
        AND `employers_description`.`language` IN ('en')
WHERE `post_job`.`published` = 1
    AND `post_job`.`deleted` = 0
GROUP BY `post_job`.`post_job_id`
LIMIT 25
```